# spark: use lookup in map

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to use lookup inside a map (in spark) in the way described below (using PySpark), and get an error.

Is this something that Spark just does not allow doing?

```
>>> rdd1 = sc.parallelize([(1,'a'),(2,'b'),(3,'c'),(4,'d')]).sortByKey()
>>> rdd2 = sc.parallelize([2,4])
>>> rdd = rdd2.map(lambda x: (x, rdd1.lookup(x)))
>>> rdd.collect()
```

The reason for doing this is that in the actual problem I am working on, rdd1 is huge. so a solution like converting it to a dictionary using a method like `collectAsMap` is not effective.

both rdd1 and rdd2 are very large so joining them is also extremely slow

Thanks

The error:

```
16/03/28 05:02:28 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 1.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/03/28 05:02:28 INFO DAGScheduler: Stage 1 (sortByKey at <stdin>:1) finished in 0.148 s
16/03/28 05:02:28 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 1 finished: sortByKey at <stdin>:1, took 0.189587 s
>>> rdd2 = sc.parallelize([2,4])
>>> rdd = rdd2.map(lambda x: (x, rdd1.lookup(x)))
>>> rdd.collect()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.2-1.cdh5.3.2.p0.10/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 676, in collect
    bytesInJava = self._jrdd.collect().iterator()
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.2-1.cdh5.3.2.p0.10/lib/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 2107, in _jrdd
    pickled_command = ser.dumps(command)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.2-1.cdh5.3.2.p0.10/lib/spark/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 402, in dumps
    return cloudpickle.dumps(obj, 2)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.2-1.cdh5.3.2.p0.10/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 816, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.2-1.cdh5.3.2.p0.10/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 133, in dump
    return pickle.Pickler.dump(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 562, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.2-1.cdh5.3.2.p0.10/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 254, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj, [themodule])
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.2-1.cdh5.3.2.p0.10/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 304, in save_function_tuple
    save((code, closure, base_globals))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 548, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 600, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 636, in _batch_appends
    save(tmp[0])
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.2-1.cdh5.3.2.p0.10/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 249, in save_function
    self.save_function_tuple(obj, modList)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.2-1.cdh5.3.2.p0.10/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 309, in save_function_tuple
    save(f_globals)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.2-1.cdh5.3.2.p0.10/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 174, in save_dict
    pickle.Pickler.save_dict(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 686, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 331, in save
    self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.2-1.cdh5.3.2.p0.10/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 650, in save_reduce
    save(state)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.2-1.cdh5.3.2.p0.10/lib/spark/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line 174, in save_dict
    pickle.Pickler.save_dict(self, obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict
    self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems
    save(v)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.2-1.cdh5.3.2.p0.10/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 538, in __call__
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.3.2-1.cdh5.3.2.p0.10/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 304, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JError: An error occurred while calling o51.__getnewargs__. Trace:
py4j.Py4JException: Method __getnewargs__([]) does not exist
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:333)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:342)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:252)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is this something that Spark just does not allow doing?

Yes there is. Spark doesn't support nested actions nor transformations. Since you already covered `join` and local variables pretty much the only option left is to use external system (database for example) for lookups.

Answer (score 0):

RDD can not be used in a process of RDD.Such as :
we have two rdd:`rdd1` and `rdd2`.
You can do this: `rdd1.map(......)`
But you can not do this: `rdd1.map(.....rdd2....)`
So,try to union/join these when you what to do some complex action.